# sort the display of labels velosurf

Tags: velocity

during my searching, I would like some tips about this case:

I have a table in my database with different labels to display in my webpage and I would like to sort the display of the labels according to a column called "display_order" in my table.

I looked for the Velosurf API and I saw the method:

> sortColumns(List, List, List) - Method in class velosurf.sql.ReverseEngineer
>       Sort columns in target the same way unordered would have to be sorted to be like ordered.

Is It that? Don't hesitate to give me a piece of advice

Ale

Comment: I have a look now in velosurf packages

Comment: The method you refer to is a **private** method of the ReverseEngineer class, which is itself only internally used by Velosuf, so it's certainly not what you need. There are several ways to sort results, like adding an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query (in your _model.xml_ file), or using the _setOrder()_ method.

Comment: Ah thanks Mr. Brisson